# SQL: Aggregating strings together

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

What is the best way to group records together by one field, and get a comma-separated list of the values from another?
So if I have:

```
UserID        Code
  1            A
  1            C5
  1            X
  2            V3
  3            B
  3            D
  3            NULL
  3            F4
  4            NULL
```

I'd get:

```
 UserID        Code
  1            A,C5,X
  2            V3
  3            B,D,F4
  4            NULL
```

I'm using SQL Server 2005 database. Thanks for any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use GROUP BY to concatenate strings in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273238/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
WITH Data AS (
    SELECT 1 UserId, 'A' Code 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1, 'C5'
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1, 'X'
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2, 'V3'
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 3, 'B'
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 3, 'D'
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 3, NULL
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 3, 'F4'
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 4, NULL
)
SELECT U.UserId, STUFF((
    SELECT ','+Code FROM Data WHERE Data.UserID = U.UserID FOR XML PATH('')
), 1, 1, '') Code 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT UserID FROM Data) U
```

Just replace the `Data` CTE with your table name and you're done.

Comment: -1 for not keeping with output (this would fail an ACM programming contest question). Output has ',' not ', ' as delimiter

Comment: @Richard, I hope you got some satisfaction for that... Anyways, I fixed it, thanks for the hint.

Comment: I thought the -1 would get your attention :) Didn't actually follow through with a vote. +1

Comment: @Richard, I see, thanks... I usually try to follow up on comments, regardless of votes ;)

Answer (score 2):

There it´s  a complete review of forms to do that in TSQL

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/