# concatenating values from string column in aggregate query in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL: Aggregating strings together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452681/sql-aggregating-strings-together)

Hi, 
 I have some data which looks like this for example:

```
TYPE     FOOD
Fruit    Orange
Fruit    Apple
Fruit    Pear
Vegetable  Carrot
Vegetable  Cabbage
```

And i want to write a query to give group by the "TYPE" column and concatenate the values in the "FOOD" column as a comma separated list, so the results would be:

```
Fruit  Orange,Apple,Pear
Vegetable Carrot,Cabbage
```

How would i do this?

Thanks 
 A