# How to have DISTINCT csv in a column A grouped by column B

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, csv, group-by

Here is the sample data I have in table `T1`

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (TRANS_ID INT , SCENARIO VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (1,'DA_HRNM'),(1,'DA_HRNM'),(2,'DA_KW'),(2,'DA_HRC'),(3,'DA_BOG'),(3,'DA_HRC'),(3,'DA_HRC')
```

I want to write a query to return following output -

[image: Expected Output]

Basically I want `DISTINCT` comma separated values in `col SCENARIO GROUP BY TRANS_ID`

Comment: Google:  "sql server aggregate string concatenation".

Comment: possible duplicate of [concatenating values from string column in aggregate query in sql server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473947/concatenating-values-from-string-column-in-aggregate-query-in-sql-server)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simulating group\_concat MySQL function in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-sql-server)

Comment: Thank you @FelixPamittan and others for posting the URLs. I will go through it, as of now, I feel I may be able to get csv values after reading up on the links but how will I get DISTINCT csv ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You neeed `distinct` and `for xml path`

[**sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5d2bf/5)

```
WITH onlyone as (
      SELECT DISTINCT TRANS_ID, SCENARIO
      FROM T1 T
)    
SELECT  DISTINCT p.TRANS_ID, 
        STUFF(( SELECT ',' + CAST(T.SCENARIO as varchar(10) )
                FROM onlyone T
                WHERE T.TRANS_ID = p.TRANS_ID
                ORDER BY T.SCENARIO
                FOR
                   XML PATH('')
                ), 1, 1, '') AS SCENARIO
FROM onlyone p
```

Comment: Your query gives me duplicate csv in first and last row. The expected output is to get distinct csv value.

Comment: Try now. I add a cte to remove duplicated

Comment: Thank you @Juan! That is exactly what I was looking for!