# How to create a Pipe delimited text file in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I need to create a `stored procedure` that would create a `pipe delimited text` file based on user requirements.

The `table` that I will use has only 6 columns with names different from user required fields.

Also, the number of columns that user wants is 23. Some of them we do not have data for. I just need to display them in the `text file`.

I'm not sure how to display the data lined up under appropriate column while skipping other optional columns.

I think I would need something like this:

```
OptionalColumn 1|DataColumn 1|OptionalColumn 2|DataColumn 2
                  12/12/2015                      Name 1
                  12/12/2015                      Name 2
```

Or some other formatting for pipe delimited file.

How would I approach this?
Never done something like this.

Comment: Do you have the ability to use SSIS?  This is what it exists for.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably concatenate your fields with a simple select like

```
SELECT  '|' + YOUR_COLUMN_NAME
```

If you need more elaborate selections then perhaps this Stack Overflow approach may give you ideas [Comma Separated results in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18870326/comma-separated-results-in-sql)
The example creates a comma separated list, but the principle is the same. It allows for concatenation of data from multiple rows for a same id.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you might be able to just use concatenation if your output is always consistent....

```
Select 'col1|col2|col3|coln....'
union
Select '' as extracol + '|' + realcol + '|' + '' as extracol2 + '|' + realcol2 +'...';
```

..which will produce a String with headers

if you need to discover the structure dynamically that's a different story, you'll have to use the system tables, but this might be a simple solution. Also if you have a ton of rows, this is not a great approach. **If your app is going to stream entries to a file, it may be best to have your app create the file format, not the database stored proc**