# SQL Server - Comma separated result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using a query below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    DTL.DTL_ITEM_CRC DTL_ITEM_CRC, 
    PWK.PWK_PROMN_WEEK_KEY PWK_PROMN_WEEK_KEY, 
    HDR.HDR_VENDR_NBR HDR_VENDR_NBR, 
    HDR.HDR_VENDR_NAME HDR_VENDR_NAME 
FROM
    DBO.PROMWEEK PWK, DBO.BLTNHDR HDR, DBO.BLTNDET DTL, DBO.ITEMWHSE ITW
WHERE 
    DTL.DTL_BULTN_KEY = HDR.HDR_BULTN_KEY 
    AND HDR.HDR_PROMN_WEEK_KEY = PWK.PWK_PROMN_WEEK_KEY 
    AND HDR.HDR_BULTN_KEY = ITW.ITW_BULTN_KEY 
    AND DTL.DTL_ITEM_NBR = ITW.ITW_ITEM_NBR  
    AND DTL.DTL_ITEM_CRC IN ('2180198') 
    AND PWK.PWK_PROMN_WEEK_KEY IN ('31','32') 
    AND GETDATE() < PWK.PWK_START_DATE  
    AND DTL_ITEM_CRC != '0000000' 
    AND DTL.DTL_TBLD_CONUS_CNTRL > 0 
    AND DTL.DTL_TBLD_CONUS_EAST > 0 
    AND DTL.DTL_TBLD_CONUS_SOUTH > 0 
    AND DTL.DTL_TBLD_CONUS_WEST > 0
    AND DTL.DTL_SPECL_SELL > 0
```

The result of this query is

```
DTL_ITEM_CRC    HDR_VENDR_NBR   HDR_VENDR_NAME  PROMO_WEEK
2180198 60531000    US COTTON LLC           31 
2180198 60531000    US COTTON LLC           32
```

I want to get the following:

```
DTL_ITEM_CRC    HDR_VENDR_NBR   HDR_VENDR_NAME  PROMO_WEEK
2180198 60531000    US COTTON LLC           31 ,32
```

I am trying the following but did not work:

```
SELECT A.DTL_ITEM_CRC ,A.HDR_VENDR_NBR, A.HDR_VENDR_NAME,STUFF((SELECT distinct ','+ PWK1.PWK_PROMN_WEEK_KEY
                                                                  FROM DBO.PROMWEEK PWK1,DBO.BLTNHDR HDR1, DBO.BLTNDET DTL1, DBO.ITEMWHSE ITW1
                                                                  WHERE A.DTL_ITEM_CRC = DTL1.DTL_ITEM_CRC 
                                                                  AND A.HDR_VENDR_NBR = HDR1.HDR_VENDR_NBR 
                                                                  AND A.HDR_VENDR_NAME = HDR1.HDR_VENDR_NAME
                                                                  AND A.PWK_PROMN_WEEK_KEY = PWK1.pwk_promn_week_key
                                                                  GROUP BY PWK1.PWK_PROMN_WEEK_KEY
                                                                  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','VARCHAR(max)'), 1, 1, '') PROMO_WEEK
FROM  
(SELECT DISTINCT DTL.DTL_ITEM_CRC DTL_ITEM_CRC, PWK.PWK_PROMN_WEEK_KEY PWK_PROMN_WEEK_KEY, HDR.HDR_VENDR_NBR HDR_VENDR_NBR, HDR.HDR_VENDR_NAME HDR_VENDR_NAME 
FROM DBO.PROMWEEK PWK, DBO.BLTNHDR HDR, DBO.BLTNDET DTL, DBO.ITEMWHSE ITW
WHERE DTL.DTL_BULTN_KEY = HDR.HDR_BULTN_KEY AND HDR.HDR_PROMN_WEEK_KEY = PWK.PWK_PROMN_WEEK_KEY 
AND HDR.HDR_BULTN_KEY = ITW.ITW_BULTN_KEY AND DTL.DTL_ITEM_NBR = ITW.ITW_ITEM_NBR  
and DTL.DTL_ITEM_CRC in ('2180198') 
AND PWK.PWK_PROMN_WEEK_KEY in ('31','32') AND GETDATE() < PWK.PWK_START_DATE  AND DTL_ITEM_CRC != '0000000' 
AND DTL.DTL_TBLD_CONUS_CNTRL > 0 AND DTL.DTL_TBLD_CONUS_EAST > 0 AND DTL.DTL_TBLD_CONUS_SOUTH > 0 AND DTL.DTL_TBLD_CONUS_WEST > 0 AND DTL.DTL_SPECL_SELL > 0 ) A
```

can you please help?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @Mulliganaceous I disagree, it's very clear what he's asking. He wants to end up with a column containing comma-delimited values, instead of a new row for each of the values in that column.

Comment: Please don't make more work for people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), for SE to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted.

Comment: @Nick Coad The post was already fixed and the formatting was done soon after I posted this. When I saw this in review it was made vandalized and unclear. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [string-agg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function in newer versions of SQL Server, but if you're on an older version you can use [XML functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18870326/comma-separated-results-in-sql) to get your desired output. The query looks horrible, but this should work (haven't tested it without sample data, so you'll probably need to tweak it):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    DTL.DTL_ITEM_CRC
    , PROMO_WEEK =
        (
        SELECT  STUFF( 
                (SELECT ', ' + PWK_PROMN_WEEK_KEY
                FROM 
                    DBO.PROMWEEK PWK
                    JOIN DBO.BLTNHDR HDR
                        ON HDR.HDR_PROMN_WEEK_KEY = PWK.PWK_PROMN_WEEK_KEY 
                    JOIN DBO.BLTNDET DTL
                        ON DTL.DTL_BULTN_KEY = HDR.HDR_BULTN_KEY 
                    JOIN DBO.ITEMWHSE ITW
                        ON DTL.DTL_ITEM_NBR = ITW.ITW_ITEM_NBR  
                        AND HDR.HDR_BULTN_KEY = ITW.ITW_BULTN_KEY 
                WHERE 
                    DTL.DTL_ITEM_CRC IN ('2180198') 
                    AND PWK.PWK_PROMN_WEEK_KEY IN ('31','32') 
                    AND GETDATE() < PWK.PWK_START_DATE  
                    AND DTL_ITEM_CRC != '0000000' 
                    AND DTL.DTL_TBLD_CONUS_CNTRL > 0 
                    AND DTL.DTL_TBLD_CONUS_EAST > 0 
                    AND DTL.DTL_TBLD_CONUS_SOUTH > 0 
                    AND DTL.DTL_TBLD_CONUS_WEST > 0
                    AND DTL.DTL_SPECL_SELL > 0
                  ORDER BY  PWK_PROMN_WEEK_KEY
                    FOR   XML PATH('') ,
                              ROOT('MyString') ,
                              TYPE 
                 ).value('/MyString[1]', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 2, ''
            )
        )
    , HDR.HDR_VENDR_NBR 
    , HDR.HDR_VENDR_NAME
FROM DBO.PROMWEEK PWK
    JOIN DBO.BLTNHDR HDR
        ON HDR.HDR_PROMN_WEEK_KEY = PWK.PWK_PROMN_WEEK_KEY 
    JOIN DBO.BLTNDET DTL
        ON DTL.DTL_BULTN_KEY = HDR.HDR_BULTN_KEY 
    JOIN DBO.ITEMWHSE ITW
        ON DTL.DTL_ITEM_NBR = ITW.ITW_ITEM_NBR  
        AND HDR.HDR_BULTN_KEY = ITW.ITW_BULTN_KEY 
WHERE 
    DTL.DTL_ITEM_CRC IN ('2180198') 
    AND PWK.PWK_PROMN_WEEK_KEY IN ('31','32') 
    AND GETDATE() < PWK.PWK_START_DATE  
    AND DTL_ITEM_CRC != '0000000' 
    AND DTL.DTL_TBLD_CONUS_CNTRL > 0 
    AND DTL.DTL_TBLD_CONUS_EAST > 0 
    AND DTL.DTL_TBLD_CONUS_SOUTH > 0 
    AND DTL.DTL_TBLD_CONUS_WEST > 0
    AND DTL.DTL_SPECL_SELL > 0
```