# How to remove quotes from particular fields in strings?

Tags: php, sql-server

I want to remove quotes from specific fields where there is an integer between the quotes.

From this line : "AAA","99"

to this line :  "AAA",99

This is my string :

```
$string='"name","99","email","112"';
```

Comment: What SQL Server version?

Comment: In PHP or in an sql-server update query?

Comment: in sql  server update query . i have to pass values with modify with that quotes in my procedure

Comment: sql server 2008

Comment: is it possible in php side ?

Comment: insteaded of numeric fields is it possible for any fields?

Answer (score 3):

1) Split by ',' into a table. (I'm using string_split, which is supported in MSSQL 2016+ - there are many ways to [implement split functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10914602/1208034) in earlier SQL versions.)
2) Use REPLACE(value, '"', '') and `ISNUMERIC` to figure out which values are numbers.
3) Use [FOR XML PATH/STUFF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18870585/1208034) to add the commas back.

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(25) = '"name","99","email","112"'

SELECT STUFF(
(
    SELECT ',' + 
        CASE 
            WHEN ISNUMERIC(REPLACE(value, '"', '')) = 1 
                THEN REPLACE(value, '"', '') 
            ELSE value 
        END
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(@str, ',')
    FOR XML PATH('')
), 1, 1, '')
```

Returns:

```
"name",99,"email",112
```

Comment: if there is any function like getdate(),e.g. $string='"name","99","email","112","getdate()"'; i have to remove quotes from getdate , how to possible ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = '"name","99","email","112"';

$string = str_replace('"', '', $string);

$strings = explode(",", $string);

foreach($strings as $key => $string) {
    $strings[$key] = preg_match('/^[0-9]*$/', $string) 
        ? intval($string) : '"'.$string.'"';
}

$string = implode(",",$strings)
```

Comment: if there is any function like getdate(),e.g. 

$string='"name","99","email","112","getdate()"'; i have to remove quotes from getdate , how to possible ?