# How to achieve string_agg function in azure data warehouse

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-synapse

i'm using the string_agg function in some query bu trying to convert it into azure sql data warehouse.How could i achieve this?
Can any one help me on this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comma separated results in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18870326/comma-separated-results-in-sql)

Answer (score 2):

As of the July release of Azure Data Warehouse, STRING_AGG is implemented.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/release-notes-10-0-10106-0

Answer (score 0):

string_agg not supported in azure data ware house.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017.
you can use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017.

By using: COALESCE

`DECLARE @Names VARCHAR(8000) 
SELECT @Names = COALESCE(@Names + ', ', '') + ColumnName 
FROM TABLE_NAME
Select @Names`

Comment: How does `COALESCE` create a delimited list? `COALESCE` is a short hand `CASE` expression.

Comment: @Larnu see this: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/how-to-concatenate-text-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-text-string-in-sql-serv)

Comment: My point was to explain to the OP, Hasan. This does work fine, until the OP needs this per row though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @hasan Mahmood and Larnu.In case if i have multiple rows then how to get  those as comma seperated values.Can you please help me on this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: @Hasan Mahmood .I have tried the code which you have mentioned earlier but i'm getting the following error(A variable that has been assigned in a SELECT statement cannot be included in a expression or assignment when used in conjunction with a from clause.)
Declare atNumbers AS Nvarchar(MAX)
SELECT  atNumbers = COALESCE(atNumbers + ',', '') + A
FROM   [dbo].[TEST1]

SELECT atNumbers

Note:at=@

Comment: @pythonUser try this: `Declare @atNumbers Nvarchar(MAX) 
SELECT @atNumbers = COALESCE(@atNumbers + ',', '') + A FROM [dbo].[TEST1] 
SELECT @atNumbers`

Comment: Thanks Hasan Mahmood for your reply . I have tried the above query which you mentioned in the comment but i'm still getting the same error as i mentioned in the earlier comment.
Can you please provide any alternate solution for this?

Comment: below is the code i have used
Declare atNumbers Nvarchar(MAX) SELECT atNumbers = COALESCE(atNumbers + ',', '') + A FROM [dbo].[TEST1] SELECT atNumbers
note:@should be added wherever it needs

Comment: @HasanMahmood: Below is the error 
Msg 104473, Level 16, State 1, Line 28
A variable that has been assigned in a SELECT statement cannot be included in a expression or assignment when used in conjunction with a from clause.

Comment: @pythonUser I need your whole code and TEST1 table structure with some sample data, BTW there are some other ways to do that as well.

Comment: @Hasan Mahmood: above one is my whole code.i want to achieve the data in comma separated values.My table structure and as follows:
Test1 table:A nvarchar(200),B nvarchar(200)
column 1data:A
abc
dfg
efh

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191460/discussion-between-hasan-mahmood-and-pythonuser).