# How to combine rows of similar results into one?

Tags: sql-server

How do i combine rows of similar results into one? For example this is what i have:

```
Title | Actor | StartYear | Genres
Noah | Adam   | 2000 | Documentary
Noah | Eve    | 2000 | Documentary
Noah | Joshua | 2000 | Documentary
Narnia | Peter | 2005 | Action
Narnia | James | 2005 | Action
```

What i want :

```
Title | Actor | StartYear | Genres
Noah | Adam, Eve, Joshua  | 2000 | Documentary
Narnia | Peter, James | 2005 | Action
```

The method provided in this link which is STRING_AGG doesn't work because what i have 10 columns. (or am i wrong? i cant execute the query if i used STRING_AGG because the other columns are not in the grouped by clause)
[Comma separated results in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18870326/comma-separated-results-in-sql)

For example, this works,

```
 SELECT primaryTitle, STRING_AGG(Actor, ', ') FROM table GROUP BY primaryTitle
```

This does not

```
SELECT primaryTitle, STRING_AGG(Actor, ', '), StartYear, Genre FROM table GROUP BY primaryTitle
```

Comment: Did you get an error when you tried the second query?   What was the error message?

Comment: so you did not get an answer in your same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56580876/how-combine-rows-of-separate-results-into-one) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comma separated results in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18870326/comma-separated-results-in-sql)

Answer (score 2):

You just need to be sure that you are grouping by all the columns you are not applying an aggregate function to. i.e.

```
SELECT primaryTitle, STRING_AGG(Actor, ', '), StartYear, Genre 
FROM table 
GROUP BY primaryTitle, StartYear, Genre
```