# How to find every genre from an artist in a music database in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So I've got a database with 4 tables: artist, genre, track and album. Track table points in a many to one way to Genre table, and so on with Track to Album, and Album to Artist.

Suppose I want to find every genre that 'John Coltrane' plays, so I thought about saying

```
SELECT DISTINCT Artist.name, Genre.name 
FROM Artist 
JOIN Genre 
JOIN Album 
JOIN Track  
WHERE Artist.name = 'John Coltrane' 
  AND Track.genre_id = Genre.genre_id
```

But this just gives me

[image]

i.e. ALL genres jointed to John Coltrane, instead of just 'Jazz' which is what I'm seeking...

Why is it not working?

Comment: You should think about `ON` conditions as well.

Comment: @GordonLinoff What is the difference between applying the Track.genre_id = Genre.genre_id with an ON and a WHERE? Anyways it doesn't work so I guess this may not be the right condition to apply, but why it's not?

Comment: *What is the difference between applying the Track.genre_id = Genre.genre_id with an ON and a WHERE?* In MySQL - no difference.

Comment: At this point, I feel a couple of hours in the company of a good introductory book or tutorial will pay dividends

Comment: Provide a fiddle. Now your problem is not clear.

Comment: Is this what you're aiming for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18870326/comma-separated-results-in-sql

Comment: Which is it?  "I want to find every genre that 'John Coltrane' plays" or " just 'Jazz' which is what I'm seeking..."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't show all the table columns which would be used to join tables together. I will make some assumptions for you. I will be more accurate if I notice that you updated the topic and I will update my answer when I see it. Where I am incorrect about the column name that I join on just substitute the actual column with the one I put here and it will do what you are trying to do. ;-)

```
SELECT DISTINCT ART.name,
       Genre.name
  FROM Artist ART
  JOIN Album ALB ON ART.artist_id = ALB.artist_id
  JOIN Track TRK ON ALB.album_id = TRK.album_id
  JOIN Genre G ON TRK.genre_id = G.genre_id
 WHERE ART.name = 'John Coltrane'
```