# Convert result in Json format in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server

I want to execute a select query on a table and I need this result in a JSON format. 
I want to do this using query only in SQL Server 2014.

My data is as follows.

```
DECLARE @Country TABLE (id INT, [CounrtyName] Varchar(30) )
INSERT INTO @Country VALUES (1,'India')
INSERT INTO @Country VALUES (1,'BAN')
INSERT INTO @Country VALUES (1,'USA')
INSERT INTO @Country VALUES (2,'Japan')
INSERT INTO @Country VALUES (2,'China')
INSERT INTO @Country VALUES (3,'Switzerland')
INSERT INTO @Country VALUES (4,'')
```

My result should be as below:

```
id  CounrtyName
1   {"India":"BAN":"USA"}
2   {"Japan":"China"}
3   {"Switzerland"}
4
```

Can anyone please suggest me the query for the above data.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? `FOR JSON` isn't available in SQL Server 2014 (though as Martin mentions, this isn't valid JSON data), but at the end of the day, this is just a Colon (`:`) delimited string wrapped in braces (`{}`); and both `STUFF` and `FOR XML PATH` *are* available in SQL Server 2014.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comma separated results in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18870326/2029983)

Comment: This is not valid JSON: `{"India":"BAN":"USA"}`

Comment: Note that the format you've suggested is not JSON. Specifically, JSON is a key/value format; `{"India":"BAN":"USA"}` is not valid. In JSON that would more naturally be represented as `{"Countries": ["India","BAN","USA"]}` or similar.

Comment: Sorry yes I need in the format of {"India","BAN","USA"} without Key

Comment: It's basically a string concatenation problem - which is why I've closed as a duplicate - you just need to play around with the parameters a bit - instead of concatenating just `,`, you need to concatenate `","`, and add `{"` to the start and `"}` to the end of your strings.

Answer (score 2):

Your expected output looks nothing like JSON. Having said that, you could use the following to generated the expected result:

```sql
SELECT id, '{' + STUFF((
    SELECT ',"' + NULLIF(CountryName, '') + '"'
    FROM @country AS y
    WHERE y.id = x.id
    FOR XML PATH('')
), 1, 1, '') + '}'
FROM @country AS x
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: I am getting "'STRING_ESCAPE' is not a recognized built-in function name" error

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: `string_escape` was introduced in 2016 version, `string_agg` in 2017. The OP is working with 2014 version, meaning no built-in JSON support hence the question...

Comment: I am using 2014 version

Comment: @Bhushan see revised answer.

Comment: It is working. Could you please provide me how to write the same in SQL SERVER 2016

Comment: It'll also work in SQL 2016. Since you're generating invalid JSON there is no point using _proper_ JSON functions.