# Convert Rows to Column - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with account numbers and products. the table looks like this:

```
ACCOUNT_NUMBER, Product
1234, 'Personal Loan'
1234, 'Saving Account'
1234, 'Auto Loan'
4321, 'Checking Account'
4321, 'Mortgage'
```

I would like to have a query to give the result in this format:

```
ACCOUNT_NUMBER, PRODUCTS
1234,'Personal Loan,Savinig Account, Auto Loan'
4321, 'Checking Account,Mortgage'
```

how would I achieve that? I tried XML PATH, but the performance was very bad and it throws error (server out of disk spacee)

Comment: *" I tried XML PATH"* Show us what you tried then, please. This sounds like you didn't use a correlated query.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comma separated results in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18870326/comma-separated-results-in-sql)

Answer (score 2):

It is 2020, so let's try to stay current and use the latest available `STRING_AGG` function in SQL Server:

```
SELECT
    ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
    STRING_AGG(Product, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Product) AS PRODUCTS
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    ACCOUNT_NUMBER
ORDER BY
    ACCOUNT_NUMBER;
```

There does not appear to be any rule for determining the order of products within the CSV list, so I am using the product name itself for that purpose.  If you have other ordering logic, then state it and this answer can be modified.

Comment: I got an error that STRING_AGG is not recognized built-in function name.
I am using SQL Server 2016 13.0.5102 (x64)

Comment: Time to upgrade `:-)`

Comment: @MoeMoney The function was added in SQL Server 2017. Refer to Yogesh Sharma's answer for the very arcane alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *xml* approach :

```
select t.account_number, 
       stuff( (select concat(', ', t1.Product)
               from table t1
               where t1.account_number = t.account_number
               for xml path('')
              ), 1, 1, ''
            ) as products
from (select distinct account_number
      from table t
     ) t;
```

For recent version, you can use [STRING_AGG()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).