# Distinct few Columns and check condition on the column not included in distinct columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Table "Module" has these columns

[image]

How to select distinct columns of ModuleGroupDisplayAs and ModuleGroup And After that, Add column on checking these distinct columns has particular UserID and CompanyID. That means I want to check condition that distinct columns has this particular userID and CompanyID. The expected result would be as following.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comma separated results in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18870326/comma-separated-results-in-sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you just need to group by the last two columns and use a `case` expression to determine yes/no, but want Yes to override No to remove duplicates, for which you can use aggregations

```
select  
    Max(case when UserID='agnes' and CompanyID='aud' then 'Yes' else 'No' end) as [Include?],
    ModuleGroupDisplayAs, ModuleGroup
from Module
group by ModuleGroupDisplayAs, ModuleGroup
```