# How to combine multiple rows into one ,getting the one column that differs as comma separated values in t-sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to combine multiple rows into one, getting the one column that differs as comma-separated values.

I have written the below query and it gives the result as shown below.
I want 4 rows instead of 9, the last column should appear comma separated like (Storage, Wastewater, Misc).

Please help with your ideas, Thanks in advance!

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    C.CONTRACTID, C.NUMBER, C.STATE,  
    O.CUSTOMERCODE, O.CUSTOMERNAME,
    C.STARTDATE, C.TERMINATIONDATE, CT.Name AS CONTRACTTYPELIST
FROM  
    [DBO].[CONTRACT] C  
INNER JOIN  
    [ORD].[ORDER] O ON C.CUSTOMERID = O.CUSTOMERID 
INNER JOIN
    [dbo].[Contract_ContractType] CCT ON CCT.ContractId =  C.ContractId
INNER JOIN 
    [Ref].[ContractType] CT ON CT.ContractTypeId = CCT.ContractTypeId
WHERE 
    O.ORDERSTATEID = 6 
ORDER BY 
    c.ContractId
```

[image]

I updated the query like below , but it gives long string in the last column but i want only values for that particular record id in one row. How can this be corrected ?

```
SELECT distinct 
   C.CONTRACTID,C.NUMBER, C.STATE , 
   O.CUSTOMERCODE,O.CUSTOMERNAME ,
   C.STARTDATE , C.TERMINATIONDATE ,
   STRING_AGG(CAST(CT.Name AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) , ',') AS CONTRACTTYPELIST
FROM 
  [DBO].[CONTRACT] C  
INNER JOIN 
  [ORDERING].[ORDER] O ON C.CUSTOMERID = O.CUSTOMERID 
INNER JOIN
   [dbo].[Contract_ContractType] CCT on CCT.ContractId =  C.ContractId
INNER  JOIN 
   [Ref].[ContractType] CT on CT.ContractTypeId = CCT.ContractTypeId
WHERE 
   O.ORDERSTATEID =  6 
GROUP BY  
C.CONTRACTID,C.NUMBER, C.STATE  , 
O.CUSTOMERCODE,O.CUSTOMERNAME ,
C.STARTDATE , C.TERMINATIONDATE
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comma separated results in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18870326/comma-separated-results-in-sql)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comma separated results in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18870326/comma-separated-results-in-sql)

Answer (score 2):

You want to use a `GROUP BY` clause together with the `STRING_AGG` function

Example:

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(column_D, ',')
FROM dbo.table
GROUP BY column_A, column_B, column_C
```

Comment: hi ,I updated the post ,I tried after updating the query but it gives long string in the last column but i want only values for that particular record id in one row. How can this be corrected ?

Comment: Are you sure there aren’t more records with contractId 12 than the 3 you show in your picture? This would explain the result you get.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the query with the DISTINCT in a sub-query.
Then use STRING_AGG in the outer query.

```
SELECT 
  CONTRACTID, [NUMBER], STATE, 
  CUSTOMERCODE, CUSTOMERNAME,
  STARTDATE, TERMINATIONDATE,
  STRING_AGG(CONTRACTTYPE,',') AS CONTRACTTYPELIST
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
      C.CONTRACTID, C.NUMBER, C.STATE, 
      O.CUSTOMERCODE, O.CUSTOMERNAME,
      C.STARTDATE, C.TERMINATIONDATE,
      CT.Name AS CONTRACTTYPE
    FROM 
      [DBO].[CONTRACT] C  
    JOIN [ORDERING].[ORDER] O 
      ON C.CUSTOMERID = O.CUSTOMERID 
    JOIN [dbo].[Contract_ContractType] CCT 
      ON CCT.ContractId =  C.ContractId
    JOIN [Ref].[ContractType] CT 
      ON CT.ContractTypeId = CCT.ContractTypeId
    WHERE 
       O.ORDERSTATEID =  6 
) q
GROUP BY  
  CONTRACTID, [NUMBER], STATE, 
  CUSTOMERCODE, CUSTOMERNAME,
  STARTDATE, TERMINATIONDATE
```