# Grouping subquery and use concat_ws() to separate and combine result set

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have written query by combining two tables and result looks like below mentioned

Result Set

| recipient_email | recipient_name | accrual_deadline | CCA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| siva@gmail.com | siva | jun 24 | reddy@gmail.com |
| siva@gmail.com | siva | jun 24 | sa@gmail.com |
| mohan@gmail.com | mohan | jun 24 | ma@gmail.com |
| mohan@gmail.com | mohan | jun 24 | run@gmail.com |

Query:

```
 SELECT te.email AS recipient_email
    ,te.employee_name AS recipient_name
    ,(
        SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(d, - 3, MAX(TRANSACTION_DATE)), 107)
        FROM [POT].[vw_Calendar]
        WHERE CURRENT_FISCAL_YEAR_FLAG = 'Y'
            AND CURRENT_FISCAL_QUARTER_FLAG = 'Y'
        ) AS accrual_deadline
    ,'GR' AS emp_type
    ,te1.email AS CostCenterAnalyst FROM [POT].[vw_POT_Open_PO] op 
    LEFT JOIN POT.vw_Employee te ON te.Employee_Number = op.Goods_Recipient_Emp_ID
    AND te.flag_Status = 'A'
    JOIN POT.vw_Employee te1 ON te1.Employee_Number = op.pocostcenteranlystid 
    LEFT JOIN [POT].[tbl_POT_Open_PO_Accrual_Reminder_History] opair ON DATEPART(month, GETDATE()) + DATEPART(year, GETDATE()) = DATEPART(month, [Mail_Sent_On]) + DATEPART(year, [Mail_Sent_On])
    AND [Recipient_Email] = te.email
    AND opair.Flag_Active = 1
    AND [Reminder_Type] = 'Accrual_Input' 
    WHERE te.email IS NOT NULL
    AND opair.Recipient_Email IS NULL
    AND te.Email IN (
        'siva@amat.com'
        ,'mohan@amat.com'
        )  GROUP BY te.email
    ,te.employee_name
    ,te1.email
```

I have to group the recipient_email and result should display like below

| recipient_email | recipient_name | accrual_deadline | CCA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| siva@gmail.com | siva | jun 24 | reddy@gmail.com; sa@gmail.com |
| mohan@gmail.com | mohan | jun 24 | ma@gmail.com; run@gmail.com |

Comment: This doesn't look like your want `CONCAT_WS`, which concatenates expressions for the current row, but `STRING_AGG` with *aggregates* strings.

Comment: I'm fine with the function, but the result should looks like I mentioned

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comma separated results in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18870326/comma-separated-results-in-sql)

Comment: This question is differ from the existing question, don't duplicate it

Comment: Can you explain *how* it's different? If you can, I'm happy to reopen, but I do agree with @Charlieface at the moment (and it's why I proposed the duplicate myself). I am sure Charlieface will be happy to cast a reopen vote too, if you can explain *why* this isn't a duplicate.

Comment: Looks like you just need to remove `te1.email` from the `group by` and the do `STRING_AGG(te1.email, '; ')`

Comment: What do you mean by it "didn't work out"? Also, you need to ping someone to make them aware you have replied, Sivamohan ( @Charlieface ) .