# How to display multiple cell values that returns from SELECT?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create a VIEW that shows a TOP 3 best selling products in June 2022, the total number of products sold in the month, the total profits and all customers who bought the specific product in June 2022. For now I tried with this:

```
CREATE VIEW INVOICE_VIEW AS
SELECT TOP 3 P.ProductName, 
    SUM(F.Quantity) AS TotalQty, 
    SUM(F.Price) AS TotalProfit, 
    C.Name + ' ' + C.LastName AS Customers
FROM PRODUCT P
INNER JOIN INVOICE F
    ON P.idProduct = F.Det_Products
LEFT JOIN CUSTOMER C
    ON F.Num_Invoice = C.Num_Invoice
WHERE F.Date BETWEEN '20220601' AND '20220630'
GROUP BY ProductName, Name, LastName
ORDER BY TotalProfit ASC
```

Using `SELECT * FROM INVOICE_VIEW` creates this:

| ProductName | TotalQty | TotalProfit | Customers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cheetos | 10 | 3 | Andrea G. |
| Ruffles | 15 | 7.5 | Kevin T. |
| DeTodito | 55 | 33 | *NULL* |

As you can see, it shows most of what I require, but in the last row it shows NULL instead of the Customer's Name. And that happens whenever a product has more than one customer.
I would like to display something like this:

| ProductName | TotalQty | TotalProfit | Customers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cheetos | 10 | 3 | Andrea G. |
| Ruffles | 15 | 7.5 | Kevin T. |
| DeTodito | 55 | 33 | Carlos Z., Robin C. |

It should show the name of all customers/clients, which could be more than 1, in the same cell.
Or at least something like this:

| ProductName | TotalQty | TotalProfit | Customer1 | Customer2 | Customer3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cheetos | 10 | 3 | Andrea G. | NULL or EMPTY | NULL or EMPTY |
| Ruffles | 15 | 7.5 | Kevin T. | NULL or EMPTY | NULL or EMPTY |
| DeTodito | 55 | 33 | Carlos Z. | Robin C. | NULL or EMPTY |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comma separated results in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18870326/comma-separated-results-in-sql)

Comment: A null value for customer in your "current results" suggests you have schema problems - perhaps you should address that first? As written, your query does not match your goal. You need to calculate totals for each product and THEN find the associated customers. One big purchase of Cheetos by Bob will hide the fact that everyone else loves Ruffles but buy smaller quantities (though the total is still higher).  And summing price is generally not "profit" - usually you sum price * quantity.

Comment: [string_agg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) could be usefull