# How to get all unique rows and also include top 1 of multiple similar rows with one column different

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get all unique rows along with considering one row of multiple rows having almost similar records with one duplicate column in the row

```
DeptId || DeptNo  ||    DeptDate
==============================
1    ||    111    ||   12-09-2021
2    ||    112    ||   12-09-2021
3    ||    113    ||   12-09-2021
1    ||    111    ||   null
1    ||    111    ||   11-09-2021

Expected result:

DeptId || DeptNo ||     DeptDate
=================================
1    ||    111   ||    null or 12-09-2021 or 11-09-2021 //Consider any but
// only one row should be considered
2    ||    112   ||    12-09-2021
3    ||    113   ||    12-09-2021
```

Comment: SQL Server and MySQL are completely different problems. I've removed these conflicting tags; please [edit] your question to (re)tag the (R)DBMS you are really using.

Comment: `STRING_AGG`/`GROUP_CONCAT`?

Comment: Modified the question, plz check on the problem statement now

Comment: Probably you are after a simple aggregation `max(DeptDate)` but it's not clear.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comma separated results in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18870326/comma-separated-results-in-sql)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT DeptId,DeptNo  
      ,STRING_AGG(CAST(DeptDate AS VARCHAR(MAX)), '/')
FROM table
GROUP BY DeptId,DeptNo
```

or

```
SELECT DeptId,DeptNo  
      ,MAX(DeptDate)
FROM table
GROUP BY DeptId,DeptNo
```

if you need only one of the values.