# Comma-separated values in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, csv

I have three tables with relationship.

TableDetail

```
ID(PK), TableNo
```

BookingDet

```
ID(PK), BookID(FK BookingMstr.BookID), TblID(FK TableDetail.ID)
```

BookingMstr

```
BookID(PK), Date
```

I want to get table list comma separated for each `Booking`

```
TableDetail
1  1
2  2

BookingDetail
1 1 1
2 1 2
3 2 1

Result Table
1 1,2
```

I have tried [This query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0c7d6/2) but gives me values like

```
    (ID) (TableNo)
      1    1,2,1 
      2    1,2,1
```

But I want it like

```
    1  1,2,1
```

Thanks.

Comment: What are your expected results from the fiddle you posted?

Comment: Basically I want to show all bookings that shows `ClientName, NoOfPersons, Date, TABLE_LIST (this must be comma separated because client can book more than one table)`, and others.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452681/sql-aggregating-strings-together